# Crystal Report printing reports directly to printer prints garbage values in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, crystal-reports

I have a WPF application written in C# where i directly send the report to printer without preview,when i do that garbage values are being printed on the print out page.However if  i use ExportToDisk and download the report to my desktop the report is being downloaded with proper content .This code written is just a conversion of an existing older VB.NET webforms application where i was able to print to printer successfully.

```
                                ReportDocument ObjDoc = new ReportDocument();

                                cocPrinting.FetchReportDataforUTEnglish(pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["DOCMFRAN"].ToString().Trim(), pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["DOCMBRCD"].ToString().Trim(), pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["DOCMDPCD"].ToString().Trim(), pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["DOC_NO"].ToString().Trim(), pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["DOCMBANNER"].ToString().Trim(), pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["COPY_TYPE"].ToString().Trim(), lsOrgDup, ref cdtUTDocEng, lsErr);
                                ObjDoc.Load("//Server Name//Crystal_Reports//VHRSSALEFDE002.rpt");
                                if (cdtUTDocEng.Rows.Count > 0)
                                    ObjDoc.SetDataSource(cdtUTDocEng);
                                else
                                {
                                    lsPrintMessage = "Printing Failed -Failed to fetch Undertaking English details";
                                    break;
                                }


                                if (cEnvironment.Production == psEnvironment)
                                {
                                    // ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait
                                    // ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4
                                    ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterDuplex = PrinterDuplex.Default;
                                    lsPrinterName = cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
                                    if (CheckifPrinterInstalled(cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim()) == true)
                                    {
                                        // ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim()
                                        ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
                                        ObjDoc.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
                                        ObjDoc.Dispose();

                                        lsPrintMessage = lsPrintMessage + "Full documentation English " + pdtPrintDetails.Rows[lirow]["COPY_TYPE"].ToString().Trim() + " has been sent to printer " + cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() + @" \r\n";
                                    }
                                    else
                                        lsPrintMessage = "This printer " + cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() + " is not installed on server,cannot print";
                                }
                                if (cEnvironment.Development == psEnvironment)
                                {
                                    ExportFormatType formatType = ExportFormatType.NoFormat;
                                    formatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                                    ObjDoc.ExportToDisk(formatType, exportPath + "\\UndertakingEnglishDoc.pdf");
                                    ObjDoc.Dispose();
                                    lsPrintMessage = lsPrintMessage + "Undertaking English Doc downloaded to desktop";
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue we need to call an overloaded method of PrintToPrinter and pass printer setting and page settings to it, instead of the one mentioned in the code above.Below is the solution

```
     ReportDocument ObjDoc = new ReportDocument();
     System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
     CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings PrintLayout = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings();
     System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
     System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings);
     System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pageSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings);
  //get your details in Dataset     

ObjDoc.Load("//ServerName//Crystal_Reports//VHRSSALEPDU001.rpt");   ObjDoc.SetDataSource(YourDataset);
ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterDuplex = PrinterDuplex.Default;
lsPrinterName = cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
ObjDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = cmbPrinter.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();                                     ObjDoc.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pSettings, false, PrintLayout);
ObjDoc.Dispose();
```

Need only 2 dll for this

1. CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
2. CrystalDecisions.Shared